# Stripe payment email

Tags: php, email, testing, stripe-payments, phpmailer

I'm using PHP, is there a way of sending emails when a successful payment is done in Stripe for TEST ACCOUNT other than sending it manually from the dashboard using any code or alternative ways?

EDIT1: I've added phpmailer code to my file and it says email sent but I didn't receive any emails. I've tried it in a contact form in another page it works but when I add it in the file where there is stripe (with some changes) it doesn't work. Here is the code in thankYou.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit_2'])) {
  $mail = new PHPMailer();
  $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
  $mail->IsSMTP();
  $mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
  $mail->Port = 465;
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
  $mail->addAddress($_POST['email']);


  $mail->Username = "myemail";
  $mail->Password = "mypassword";

  $mail->IsHTML(true);
  $mail->SingleTo = true;

  $mail->From = "myemail";
  $mail->Subject = "Stripe";
  $mail->Body = "Test";

  if(!$mail->Send())
      echo "Message was not sent <br />PHPMailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
      echo "Email sent";
}

 // Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
 // See your keys here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(STRIPE_PRIVATE);

 // Get the credit card details submitted by the form
$token = isset($_POST['stripeToken'])? $_POST['stripeToken']:'';
 // Get the rest of the post data
$full_name = isset($_POST['full_name'])? sanitize($_POST['full_name']):'';
$email = isset($_POST['email'])? sanitize($_POST['email']):'';
$street = isset($_POST['street'])? sanitize($_POST['street']):'';
$street2 = isset($_POST['street2'])? sanitize($_POST['street2']):'';
$city = isset($_POST['city'])? sanitize($_POST['city']):'';
$state = isset($_POST['state'])? sanitize($_POST['state']):'';
$phone_number = isset($_POST['phone_number'])? sanitize($_POST['phone_number']):'';
$country = isset($_POST['country'])? sanitize($_POST['country']):'';
$tax = isset($_POST['tax'])? sanitize($_POST['tax']):'';
$sub_total = isset($_POST['sub_total'])? sanitize($_POST['sub_total']):'';
$grand_total = isset($_POST['grand_total'])? sanitize($_POST['grand_total']):'';
$cart_id = isset($_POST['cart_id'])? sanitize($_POST['cart_id']):'';
$description = isset($_POST['description'])? sanitize($_POST['description']):'';
$charge_amount = number_format((float)$grand_total,2) * 100;
$metadata = array(
   "cart_id"   => $cart_id,
   "tax"       => $tax,
   "sub_total" => $sub_total,
 );

 // Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
 try {
 $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
   "amount" => $charge_amount, // amount in cents, again
   "currency" => CURRENCY,
   "source" => $token,
   "description" => $description,
   "receipt_email" => $email,
   "metadata" => $metadata)
 );

//adjust inventory
$itemQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE id = '{$cart_id}'");
$iresults = mysqli_fetch_assoc($itemQ);
$items = json_decode($iresults['items'],true);
foreach($items as $item){
  $newAges = array();
  $item_id = $item['id'];
  $productQ = $db->query("SELECT ages, sold FROM products WHERE id = '{$item_id}'");
  $product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($productQ);
  $ages = agesToArray($product['ages']);
  $soldproducts = $product['sold'];
  foreach($ages as $age){
    if($age['age'] == $item['age']){
      $q = $age['quantity'] - $item['quantity'];
      $newAges[] = array('age' => $age['age'],'quantity' => $q,'threshold' => $age['threshold']);
    }else{
      $newAges[] = array('age' => $age['age'],'quantity' => $age['quantity'],'threshold' => $age['threshold']);
    }
  }
  if (isset($item['quantity'])) {
    $sold = ($soldproducts + $item['quantity']);
  }
  $ageString = agesToString($newAges);
  $db->query("UPDATE products SET ages = '{$ageString}', sold = '{$sold}' WHERE id = '{$item_id}'");
}

//update cart
 $db->query("UPDATE cart SET paid = 1 WHERE id = '{$cart_id}'");
 $db->query("INSERT INTO transactions
   (charge_id,cart_id,full_name,email,street,street2,city,state,phone_number,country,sub_total,tax,grand_total,description,txn_type)
   VALUES ('$charge->id','$cart_id','$full_name','$email','$street','$street2','$city','$state','$phone_number','$country','$sub_total',
   '$tax','$grand_total','$description','$charge->object')");

$domain = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost')? '.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']:false;
setcookie(CART_COOKIE,'',1,"/",$domain,false);
include 'includes/head.php';
include 'includes/navigation.php';
?>
  <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:100px;">
  <h1 class="text-center text-success">Thank You!</h1>
  <p> Your card has been successfully charged <?=money($grand_total);?>. You have been emailed a receipt. Please
    check you spam folder if it is not in your inbox. Additionally you can print this page as a receipt.</p>
  <p>Your receipt number is: <strong><?=$cart_id;?></strong></p>
  <p>Your order will be shipped to the address below.</p>
  <address>
    <?=$full_name;?><br>
    <?=$city. ', '.$state.' ';?><br>
    <?=$street;?><br>
    <?=$street2;?><br>
    <?=$phone_number;?><br>
  </address>
</div>
<?php
include 'includes/footer.php';
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
  // The card has been declined
  echo $e;
}
 ?>
```

And in the cart.php file (NOT ALL THE CODES):

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-6">
              <label for="email">Email:</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" type="text">
            </div>
<button type="submit" name="submit_2" class="btn btn-primary" id="checkout_button" style="display:none;">Check Out >></button>
```

Please help...

Comment: I don't have the code yet. I'm just asking is there a way to send emails on TEST ACCOUNT using php codes ... ??

Comment: Please don’t post a question, get an answer and then edit your question with a new question. Instead, post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

This is from the [Stripe API documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create?lang=php) (PHP):

receipt_email optional

The email address to which this charge’s receipt will be sent. The receipt will not be sent until the charge is paid, and no receipts will be sent for test mode charges. If this charge is for a Customer, the email address specified here will override the customer’s email address. If receipt_email is specified for a charge in live mode, a receipt will be sent regardless of your email settings

Comment: Ok, can I use phpmailer to send emails in TEST MODE ??

Comment: Test Mode is a mode in Stripe’s API, anything outside of Stripes API is not affected. So I’d say yes, as long as you have installed PHP Mailer and configured it properly etc.

Answer (score 0):

In **"test" mode**, it's totally impossible to automatically send email from **stripe** after payment even if you set [**"receipt_email" parameter**](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-receipt_email). Only in **"live" mode**, it's possible.

Actually, I couldn't find the information above on **stripe documentation** so I asked **stripe support**, then, they said so as I said above.